# Qt - QScrollBar skinning issue

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, skinning

I'm trying to skin a `QScrollBar` by reimplementing the `paintEvent` function, but I'm having trouble. I can't find any information on the buttons on the scroll bar, and I can only find (limited) information on the actual slider (the handle you can grab and drag). I looked at the QStyle as well and it still only gives information on the scroll handle and not the buttons. Hardcoding or using magic numbers is not an option because the buttons are placed differently on different operating systems (see: [Here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollbar.html)). Is there any way to programmatically get the layout of the Scrollbar, so I could accurately render the buttons and scroll handle at their correct positions?

Answer (score 0):

As the painting itself is done by underlying style, not QScrollBar itself I'd suggest following:

1. Use [QProxyStyle](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qproxystyle.html) to override painting of QScrollBar.
2. This is how does Qt [paints QScrollBar](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/gui/styles/qstylesheetstyle.cpp#line3133). You can alternate that

As alternative I'd suggest using Qt Style Sheets to change QScrollBar look'n'feel